# How to use sFTP in Filezilla?

Tags: encryption, sftp, filezilla

How to encrypt the connection with server using filezilla in Linux? I read, it is possible in Windows using Putty. Just wondering how to do it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All SFTP sessions are encrypted and authenticated by the server's host key.

If you already generated your key files, You may add it going `Edit -> Setting -> SFTP` and `Add KeyFile`

[image]

If not, You may access the server just typing like this:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the port be 22?

Comment: @王子1986 Thats just and example ;) While TCP port 22 is the general right answer, this is dependent on the fact that SSH is configured to use the standard port and not an alternative port. I change my default ssh port every time a setup a new server. e.g i use `2122`,`2020` etc...